# Angular Ionic input instantly gets "touched"

Tags: html, css, angular, forms, ionic-framework

I'm trying to show an error message when a user leaves the title input empty, but the error message appears instantly.

[image: gif error]

HTML

```
<ion-item>
        <div class="margin-bottom">
          <h5>Titel</h5>
          <ion-input
            id="title"
            class="todoTitle"
            placeholder="Titel van de taak"
            required
            ngModel
            value=""
            name="title"
            #title="ngModel"
          >
          </ion-input>
          <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="!title.valid && title.touched">
            <p class="required">Een titel is verplicht.</p>
          </ion-text>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
```

CSS

```
.todoTitle.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name implies, `touched` is `true` as soon as the control is visited. Most probably you're looking for `dirty`. It's set to `true` when the input value changes.

```html
<ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="!title.valid && title.dirty">
  <p class="required">Een titel is verplicht.</p>
</ion-text>
```

```css
.todoTitle.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

See [Track Control States](https://angular.io/guide/forms#track-control-states) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You want `ng-dirty` for a field that has had the input used. Touched will indicate that it has been focused by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `dirty` instead of touched.

```
<ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="!title.valid && title.dirty">
  <p class="required">Een titel is verplicht.</p>
</ion-text>
```